# Gradle jacoco plugin: how to print the location of the HTML report at the end of the task execution?

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I added the jacoco aggregation plugin to my build

```
plugins {
    id("jacoco-report-aggregation")
}
```

When I run the task `./gradlew testCodeCoverageReport`, the report is correctly generated in `build/reports/jacoco/testCodeCoverageReport/html/index.html` but it's kinda painful to lookup the file.

How can I simply automate gradle to print the path in the build log?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

```
tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
    val reports = reports
    doLast {
        println("HTML report generated: " + reports.html.entryPoint)
    }
}
```